# I need a desired table format in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

TeacherApprover Table - Table format in Database

```
TeacherID   ApproverID  ApproverLevel
15122                4                1
15122                2                2
15122                3                3
```

i need the result as in select Statement- it should display as below

```
TeacherID   ApproverID  ApproverID2`    ApproverID3
15122             4              2                3
```

i tried directly binding in front end but i have some issues after binding like this, So i want to try getting the result in Dataset directly from backend.
please guide me

Comment: very short on details. be clearer on what you need and how you need it.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15745042/2914428). This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need approver id by teacher Id.
So I think you can get data using query,

> ```
> SELECT ApproverID  from table_name  where teacherID = 15122;
> ```

Then handle the result according to your requirement.

1. Create new table having column as you needed.
2. insert into that new table .

> ```
> INSERT INTO table2
> (column_name(s))
> SELECT column_name(s)
> FROM table1;
> ```